# Prep drywall before backsplash

Tags: drywall, tile, mortar, backsplash, drywall-mud

I'm looking to put up some new backsplash. I took off the old tile as carefully as possible, but some drywall was damaged. I put one hole in the wall which I will patch, but the rest, as you can see in the pictures, is in rough shape. The drywall is still solid, but the top paper ripped off in a lot of spots, and in some spots the glue is still showing.

[image]

[image]

I'm wondering the best way to prep before starting. Can I take all the paper off and tile right over the brown paper on drywall? Should I run some drywall mud over? Maybe do a thin layer of mortar and let it dry then tile over that?

Thanks for help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I were you, I'd install some backer board or gypsum board first. The backer board can directly attach to the wall and provide better adhesion for your tile. They're available in 1/4" thick so it shouldn't add too much to the wall.

Comment: Thanks for reply. So I can add backer board directly over how it currently is? Would I just tape the joints of backer board with mesh tape and mortar?

Comment: Correct. Some backer board recommends mortar between the backer and the surface below, but in this case some construction adhesive might suffice. You don't need to modify the wall much because it looks scraped and you'll be screwing/nailing to the studs